# Distinguish read char from read integer

Tags: c, char

I am implementing RLE algorithm in C, and I'm having a great problem. I am using @ as an identifier for the compression/decompression. Let me use examples:

0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 = @ 0 4 1 2 @ 0 4

Kind of @ X Y = repeat X, Y times. And the numbers vary from 0 to 255 (unsigned char). But, the number 64 is screwing me, because it is the same as '@'.

The program reads 64 0 5

I expect: 64 0 5 (no decompression is needed)

What I get: 0 0 0 0 0 (64 is stored in a char variable, and then, the program uses it as '@')

```
if (var == '@') {
    // decompress
}
```

Comment: How are you converting the `unsigned char` into integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're using some `scanf`-like function to parse your input.

Don't. It won't work in this case.

Instead, simply read the input string, split it by whitespace into tokens (examples: `"@ 0 4 1 2 @ 0 4"` --> `"@", "0", "4", "1", "2", "@", "0", "4"` and `"64 0 5"` --> `"64", "0", "5"`).

Next step is parsing. There you can weed out the `@`-s. It'll be easy to tell them apart from the `64`-s as `strlen("@") == 1` and `strlen("64") == 2`, you see ;)

And when you encounter a purely-numeric string, you can use something like [`atoi`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) to convert it to an integer (and after that you're free to convert it to `unsigned char`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a character sequence that's definitely not going to be used as an escape mechanism. If you're transforming the input into `@ <character> <count>` if there are at least 3 consecutive occurrences of the same character, the worst input that you don't transform has 2 consecutive @ characters.

Another worst case in input is having 64 @ characters, which produces `@ @ @`. So, we're sure the output cannot contain more than 3 consecutive @'s.

In light of this, you can represent single @ character as `@@@@`, which produces 4 characters. As seen above, the output of RLE cannot have 4 consecutive @'s (or any other 4 consecutive characters, in that manner)

But instead, if you **always** transform @ into `@ @ <count>`, you can conserve a byte and you will only need to modify the RLE creation parts of your project, since this format is perfectly fine according to a RLE parser.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way to resolved the issue, but it does the job. c compiler automatically converts int to char and char to int at need. If you can find a way to restrict this behavior the problem is resolved. I have restricted the behavior via converting the character to `respective ASCII` and comparing it with `ASCII value` of `@`.

*The obvious issue with the program is that it reads individual characters, and it will never come across 64 as a whole, but even if we modify the program to split numbers with space as delimiter I do not think that would be any problem*

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main()
    {
        char s[]= "64 0 5 @ 0 5";
        int length = strlen(s);
        int i = 0;
        char ch;
        while((ch = s[i]) != '\0')
        {
            int charASCII = ch;
            if(charASCII == 64)
                printf("Perform Algorithm\n");
            else
                printf("Do not Perform Algorithm\n");
            i++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution for escaping the repeat instruction is having a repeated character.

Let me explain:

encode `0 0 0 0` as `0 0 2` (2 meaning to repeat 2 more times the previous character)

just be careful for 2 times repetitions:

`3 4 4 5`  should be encoded as `3 4 4 0 5`,

0 meaning that no more '4' follow.

When decoding just look for a repeated character and, when found, get the next character as the number of times to repeat it.

Untested example:

```
int input_char(void);
void output_char(int);

void encode(void) {
    int c, previous_c = EOF;
    int repeating = 0, repetitions;

    while ((c = input_char()) != EOF) {
        if (repeating) {
            if (c == previous_c && repetitions < 255) {
                ++repetitions;
            } else {
                output_char(repetitions);
                output_char(c);
                repeating = 0;
            }
        } else {
            output_char(c);
            if (previous_c == c) {
                repeating = 1;
                repetitions = 0;
            }
        }
        previous_c = c;            
    }
}

void decode(void)
{
    int c, previous_c = EOF;

    while ((c = input_char()) != EOF) {
        output_char(c);
        if (c == previous_c) {
            int repetitions = (unsigned char) input_char();

            while (repetitions--) {
                output_char(c);
            }
        }
        previous_c = c;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/): you can see the range that is for numbers, use that to determine whether you're reading a number or not:

```
if (var >= 48 && var <= 57) {/* I'm an integer */}
```